# In "Jacob's Ladder", what is the significance of Jacob mistaking left and right sides of his body?

Tags: dialogue, jacobs-ladder

While I didn't have a problem deciphering most of the allusions and allegorical scenes in the movie *Jacob's Ladder*, this one still bugs me.

Several times throughout the movie, Louie asks Jacob to turn onto his right side, Jacob turns to his left, and Louie tells him to turn onto "his other right". Is this significant or alluding to something, or is it just a meaningless running gag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TV Tropes officially lists it as ["Your *Other* Left"](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/YourOtherLeft), indicating it's a running gag.  I don't see how it could be taken any other way, as there's never been any indication previously in any work that spirits were prone to forgetting the difference.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that this faintly echoes the fact that Jacob is "confused about where he is". Given two possible locations, he currently perceives himself in the wrong one.